# Force a group of dynamic links to hold still?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, pagination, position

I have a group of links used for paging, like so:

[image]

As you navigate through the pages, the links change based on which page you're on. This changes the total width that they take up and causes them to move all over the place, making it really ineffective as a convenient paging tool.

Here's an example of how wide they as you go deeper:

[image]

What I need is for these links to maintain their positions and for their container to maintain its width. I'm no CSS expert, but I'd greatly appreciate it if somebody could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
.line {
    display: table;
    width: 60%;  /* width of the group of navigation links, randomly set to 60% */
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.unit, .unit-outside {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 5%;
}
.unit-outside {
    /* 'extends' the .unit class */
    width: 12.5%;
}
```

-

```
<nav class="line">
    <!--this contains all the navigation links -->
    <a class="unit-outside" href=""> First </a>
    <a class="unit-outside" href=""> Prev </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 1 </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 2 </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 3 </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 4 </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 5 </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 6 </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 7 </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 8 </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> &hellip; </a>
    <a class="unit" href=""> 66 </a>
    <a class="unit-outside" href=""> Next </a>
    <a class="unit-outside" href=""> Last </a>
</nav>
```

Essentially, the `.line` class acts like a `<table>` element (but is not semantically so) and the `.unit` classes act like `<td>` elements. This or something similar should give you the layout that you want and keep each 'cell', as well as the entire line, a consistent width.

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Nice. Looks like this assumes there are always 10 page links and 4 Next/Last links, so that the `5%` cells add up to 50% and the `12.5%` cells add up to 50%. This should be pretty easy to adjust with a calculator. Why is `.line` set to 60% though?

Comment: @brentonstrine I just chose an aesthetically pleasing width for the group of links. I figured 100% would be too big. As a matter of fact, my answer is just a template that the OP is free to modify to meet his/her needs. Thanks for the positive feedback!

Comment: Just use a `div` instead of `nav`, as long as it has the `.line` class given in the demo code, it should work the same. BTW, you can make your browser support HTML5 if you use Google's [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Answer (score 1):

Give each link a fixed width. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/3HQTN/)) Assuming you won't have any pages higher than 999, set the width of each link to assume it as 3 digits in there. I'd do it with CSS by making the link a block level element, specifying a width, and centering it--though you may want it to be right/left aligned. If you support newer browsers, you can do `inline-block`, but if not, you can set `display:block` and then `float:left`:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hm, they shouldn't really move... could you provide a link to your site or copy your code into a JSFiddle? You might also try TestSubject528491's solution, which is a really great approach if you don't need your list of links to wrap onto multiple lines when the width changes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the widths of each page number/ first / prev / next/ last to the worst case value. If it is not set it will dynamically change (get wider) when a number goes from one to two digits (5->55)